# wildfly-10 java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "module.path" "write")

Tags: security, wildfly-10

I have a wildFly-10 that I built with flag -Dsecurity.manager=yes

I have a WAR deployed to wfly.

From the command-line I am executing this cmd

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_72/jre/bin/java \
-Dsecmgr=true  -Djava.security.manager \
-Djavax.xml.ws.spi.Provider=org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl \
-Dlog4j.output.dir=/home/rsearls/j1/jbws/jbossws-cxf/modules/testsuite/cxf-tests/target \
-Dorg.jboss.ws.cxf.jaxws-client.bus.strategy=NEW_BUS \
-jar /home/rsearls/j1/wfly10/wildfly/build/target/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar \
-mp /home/rsearls/j1/wfly10/wildfly/build/target/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules \
-jar /home/rsearls/j1/jbws/jbossws-cxf/modules/testsuite/cxf-tests/target/test-libs/jaxws-cxf-jbws3713-client.jar \
http://127.0.0.1:8080/jaxws-cxf-jbws3713//HelloService?wsdl 4 5
```

I am getting this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "module.path" "write")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:792)
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:152)
```

I've tried add a ref to a policy file like this,

```
-Djava.security.policy=/tmp/yy/server.policy \
```

The causes the run exception to be

```
An existing security manager was detected.  You must use the -secmgr switch to start with a security manager.
```

I've tried various forms of secmgr

```
-secmgr
-Dsecmgr
-D-secmgr
```

but same exception

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Option "java.security.manager" is no longer supported use "-secmgr" instead.  And must place -secmgr after the jboss-modules.jar reference.